# SoapExtension not logging request and response

Tags: c#, console-application, java-ws

I consume Java Web Service with my c# console client. I need to get request and response. How can I do this with SoapExtension.

I realize TraceExtension Class like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

// Define a SOAP Extension that traces the SOAP request and SOAP 
// response for the XML Web service method the SOAP extension is 
// applied to. 

namespace WSTracer
{
    public class TraceExtension : SoapExtension
    {
        Stream oldStream;
        Stream newStream;
        string filename;

        // Save the Stream representing the SOAP request or SOAP response into 
        // a local memory buffer. 
        public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
        {
            oldStream = stream;
            newStream = new MemoryStream();
            return newStream;
        }

        // When the SOAP extension is accessed for the first time, the XML Web 
        // service method it is applied to is accessed to store the file 
        // name passed in, using the corresponding SoapExtensionAttribute.   
        public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
        {
            return ((TraceExtensionAttribute)attribute).Filename;
        }

        // The SOAP extension was configured to run using a configuration file 
        // instead of an attribute applied to a specific XML Web service 
        // method. 
        public override object GetInitializer(Type WebServiceType)
        {
            // Return a file name to log the trace information to, based on the 
            // type. 
            return "C:\\" + WebServiceType.FullName + ".log";
        }

        // Receive the file name stored by GetInitializer and store it in a 
        // member variable for this specific instance. 
        public override void Initialize(object initializer)
        {
            filename = (string)initializer;
        }

        //  If the SoapMessageStage is such that the SoapRequest or 
        //  SoapResponse is still in the SOAP format to be sent or received, 
        //  save it out to a file. 
        public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
        {
            switch (message.Stage)
            {
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                    WriteOutput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                    WriteInput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void WriteOutput(SoapMessage message)
        {
            newStream.Position = 0;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append,
                FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);

            string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ? "SoapResponse" : "SoapRequest";
            w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + " at " + DateTime.Now);
            w.Flush();
            Copy(newStream, fs);
            w.Close();
            newStream.Position = 0;
            Copy(newStream, oldStream);
        }

        public void WriteInput(SoapMessage message)
        {
            Copy(oldStream, newStream);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append,
                FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);

            string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ?
                "SoapRequest" : "SoapResponse";
            w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString +
                " at " + DateTime.Now);
            w.Flush();
            newStream.Position = 0;
            Copy(newStream, fs);
            w.Close();
            newStream.Position = 0;
        }

        void Copy(Stream from, Stream to)
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(from);
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to);
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }

    // Create a SoapExtensionAttribute for the SOAP Extension that can be 
    // applied to an XML Web service method.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class TraceExtensionAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute
    {

        private string filename = "c:\\log.txt";
        private int priority;

        public override Type ExtensionType
        {
            get { return typeof(TraceExtension); }
        }

        public override int Priority
        {
            get { return priority; }
            set { priority = value; }
        }

        public string Filename
        {
            get
            {
                return filename;
            }
            set
            {
                filename = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and add my app.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CallerPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.5.39:7001/EisGateway/ServiceCall"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CallerPortBinding"
                contract="GNISrvRef.Caller" name="CallerPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <soapExtensionTypes>
                <add type="WSTracer.TraceExtension,WSTracer" priority="1" />
            </soapExtensionTypes>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You are mixing a `SoapExtension` from the old ASMX technology with the configuration of WCF. Just use "Add Service Reference" and use WCF Tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much, much easier to use the builtin diagnostic log tracing by adding the following entry to your web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
         <add name="traceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="c:\log\WebTrace.svclog"  />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

(Ensure that the specified directory exists before updating the config)

You can double-click on the generated svclog file and, if you have .Net framework installed, it should automatically open the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has all of the details that you need.